# How can I improve the performance of passing around a large JSON object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app with React Native and on my transitions, where I'm loading more data, it's very slow and I'm wondering if there's a better way to structure my app to avoid these shutdowns, which get longer as the JSON file gets larger.

Let's say I have

`var data = require('./data/data.json')`

in my index view, I think pass this data to a view, which then splits it up to other views like `items={data[section_name]}` and it goes down recursively like that further down the hierarchy. Creating smaller dicts on each level. And even with small objects it is still quite slow.

The JSON files I'm working with are from 3-8 MBs.

Comment: is it in global scope?

Comment: May guess is that the slowdown come from what you do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want do to with your big data in your project, because I did the same way before for my react-native app.

Actually, this way is fine, it's kind of loading the data once only, then we can retrieve hierarchy easily like `items={data[section_name]}`

However, the problem now is it may take a while for processing the big data!

Therefore, the idea is we should move the part of loading/initializing the data asynchronously, move it somewhere out of our view, so that the view's transition as well as its other things will not be affected! Then, when the data are being loaded/processed, we may show something like fade-in, fade-out effects, on the view, so it will take a short-time (300-1000ms). However, in my opinion, there may be a better way for this: when the application is opened for the first time, when the splash screen is being shown (for a few seconds, this behavior is common, we can load the big data in the background here!)

FYI, my application loads big data using ajax, it will even take longer than loading local files, but using my above-mentioned way, nobody complains about the data-loading speed ^^ (actually, users don't know and don't see where and when data are loaded, when the app goes to its home/top page, everything has been fully loaded)

*Now it comes to the important part of my answer*: I suggest you using Flux/Redux for this, maybe Flux is easier for you now, because Redux is kind of an improvement based on Flux (in either Flux or Redux, we will have a Store, and this Store will work asynchronously, you can store your big JSON data here):

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/software-teams/flux-architecture-step-by-step

Flux can be applied on reactjs and react-native of course, you may find there are several new definitions if you don't know about Flux or Redux yet, however, it's really worth reading and trying! After you understand it, it'll be very easy and then you can apply that architecture on whatever react project you like ^^